# How do I reconfigure the default port or uninstall the interactive Javascript console in HDInsight?

Tags: windows-server-2012, hadoop, windows-8

The Microsoft HDInsight Preview is available for download and install via the Web Platform Installer, which bundles Hadoop on Azure installer.

As part of the process, it installs something that listens on port 8080 and serves up an interactive JavaScript console for doing MapReduce, Hive, and Pig queries.

This blocks my default port for IIS development on my deployment target, and uninstallation of both products doesn't seem to remove this console.

Looking in IIS, there is nothing hosted on port 8080. There is no add-on in Internet Explorer to remove and nothing listening on port 8080 if I use SysInternals TCPView or Netstat on console.

Where did this get hijacked into my system, and how do I remove or reconfigure it?

Comment: Sorry about the lack of cr/lf, thanks Tom

Answer (score 0):

1) You can shutdown the isotopejs Interactive Javascript console by going to the folder c:\Hadoop\isotopejs, and either executing the "stopservice" CMD (which is equivalent to "sc.exe stop isotopejs") in a subfolder or changing the config file there to use a different port and executing "stopservice" CMD then the "startservice" CMD (equivalent to executing "sc.exe stop isotopejs" and "sc.exe start isotopejs". Changing the port though may break the link on the HDInsight management portal labeled "Interactive JavaScript Console" (you can manually adjust the URL to the new port in the browser).

2) Uninstallation needs to be executed in the order: "Microsoft HDInsight..." first, then "Hortonworks Hadoop..." second, and third, "Python..." (assuming you don't still need Python for something).